# Inbox notification count in tab title bar

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

Sometimes you're not in the tab where Stack Overflow is open and therefore can't see the notification that's in the top bar of the site.

There's a notification of number of new questions:

[image: Number of new questions in page title]

So, there should also be a notification of number of new items in your inbox, which I think is actually more important.

Comment: This title makes it look in my tabs like there are 2 notifications.

Comment: @War10ck Neither the other way round, there wasn't any answer (or even constructive proposal) 'til now ;) ...

Comment: @War10ck That would be a good meta question BTW, if an older question could be marked as duplicate of a newer one in general (I don't see any obvious reason, why not. The time graph isn't a finally reasonable argument IMHO).

Comment: @War10ck Old questions can be closed as duplicates of new ones if the new ones are better written and/or phrased.

Comment: @AstroCB Either way, the phrasing is odd. Being a duplicate implies that the newly added content already exists in a prior post. Not the other way around. I can see the point your both making but the wording makes it slightly difficult for me to agree the close reason. Perhaps a discussion is needed as _@πάνταῥεῖ_ pointed out? Just me but I would have probably voted to close with a custom response stating that the new question is a better phrased alternative of this one. I'm sure most people would say I'm nitpicking thought.

Comment: @War10ck See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258703/3366929. Perhaps the 'duplicate' branding is a bit off: what we're really looking for here is one canonical question that can be linked to from questions that are asking essentially the same thing. It doesn't matter *when* the canonical question is asked as long it is the highest quality post in that network of linked "duplicates."

Comment: @AstroCB Understand the point. Just disagree with the logic behind it in its current form. I find it more annoying to jump through hoops and click multiple duplicate links. I've encountered links to "duplicates" which in and of themselves are closed as "duplicates". Probably should be a better way to handle this but I digress. Anyway, my biggest problem with it is the  use of the word "duplicate" in this case. Like I said, I'm sure most will consider this nitpicking anyway so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6):

We should have a notification notation on the tab page title like

```
(●) Newest 'javascript' ...
```

*(Zero activities, any profile event)*

```
(79●) Newest 'javascript' ...
```

*(79 new activities, any profile event)*

Where *profile event* (indicated as '●') is defined as any of

- Inbox message
- Reputation change
- Badge achievement

and *activities* is defined as the *"number of new questions"* as mentioned in your question.