# Should we really mark new questions as duplicates of old crappy ones?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, question-quality, old-questions

#### Introduction

I'm guessing this applies to all tags, but in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) we currently have issues where new questions are marked as being duplicates of older, not very well written, questions.

Surely, the old question was *first*, but it sometimes feel like it would be better to start off from scratch, writing a question that is generic enough to include minor varaities of it, and not include too much *"so this is my exact, and utterly useless, story related to the question"*-snippets.

---

#### An example

This one linked below is often being used to mark new questions as duplicates of it.

- [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1090079)

The title is very descriptive, and can't be any more generic; but the contents of the questions is a mess, which I feel can cause confusion for novice readers, which means that they are likely to just create another question because they don't understand it how it's relevant to their first one.

---

#### Questions

- Should one create a new generic and well-written question, and close the old one as a duplicate of that?
- Should one edit the old question, editing out the OPs original intent, to make it a generic "base" for new questions?
- Should one leave it as it is, even though it's mad ugly and/or confusing?

Comment: Please don't duplicate content.  I see no reason why editing the old question could not be an effective solution.

Comment: @HansPassant because it's an intrusive edit, changing the meaning of the post that the original OP's made, that is my concern.

Comment: The person who asked the question already got their answer. There's nothing wrong with editing the question to make it clearer and/or more general. Don't go through the trouble of creating a new question unless the old question is unsalvageable via editing.

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. Any "utterly useless story related to the question" can obviously be edited out without changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: @larsmans maybe that was a poor choice of words from my part, what I mean is that the post contains information on which a question is asked, in one removes such info "everyything" changes. The text is not required when a dupe is closed, but when reading the original Q&A; it is.

Comment: [Here's another relevant question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice) The timing is impeccable :). The comments explain the specifics.

Comment: wrt. the previously linked question; a decision was later made that it should be the canonical example. It was previously marked duplicate (by me, a few hours ago) of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179493/adding-backslashes-without-escaping-python).

Comment: I just suggested [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266878/encouraging-reaction-when-asker-of-a-bad-question-improves-it) (and then saw this related post) that the asker of a higher quality duplicate should be encouraged to edit the original, that has high quality answers already. A flag for mod or pseudo-close-vote that this question should replace that one would also be good in my opinion.

Answer (score 21):

> Should one create a new generic and well-written question, and close the old one as a duplicate of that?

Definitely that. The core thing that should drive this decision is usefulness to the readers. Having a canonical reference is great and really helps users.

This is a strategy users in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) tags use extensively, to great success.

Here are some good examples where there were duplicates, but they were not generic enough or well written enough:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)
- [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)
- [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)
- [Reference: Comparing PHP's print and echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo)
- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)
- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)
- [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)
- [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)
- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: That served as a great inspirational post, I actually look forward to cleaning up the mess in [tag:c++] now; thanks.

Comment: @Rapptz I don't think Benjamin's answer is a reply to that specific debate, even if I used that one as an example in my post; I interpret his text as a general *"this is the way to go"*-answer.

Comment: We also maintain our own list of often asked duplicates http://room-11.github.io/canonical.html

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that there are already too many posts pointing to the linked post. If we just close the linked post as a duplicate of the new one, all of those would take 2 steps (instead of 1) to reach the best answer. I wonder if a mass-change-of-duplicate-target is possible / viable / a good idea.

Comment: @Dukeling well, there is merging but it is very drastic as the questions are effectively only very similar but not rea`lly identical.

Answer (score 5):

> **Question**: Should one create a new generic and well-written question, and close the old one as a duplicate of that?

- **Answer:** I agree. However, we would need a creditable mechanism for this to happen. For example, a voting mechanism could be devised where according to number of votes an old question would have been deleted in favour of the new improved and generic one.

---

> **Question:** Should one edit the old question, editing out the OPs original intent, to make it a generic "base" for new questions?

- **Answer:** I believe this shouldn't be the job of one person, but rather of an informal comity, where again edit would have to be voted and if a certain amount of votes is reached the edit would be approved.

---

> **Question:** Should one leave it as it is, even though it's mad ugly and/or confusing?

- **Answer:** As Winston Churchill once said "*Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others.*" Aligned with this quote, I think that we shouldn't be afraid of changes, even if they're radical ones, provided that the decisions for making these changes are taken in a collective manner. I have the belief that through polyphony we are able to end up to the right conclusion.