# Question marked as duplicate of the Question asked at a later date

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today, I realized, a question [BeautifulSoup fails with Recursion Depth Error when running from IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14871077/977038) that I asked a year back was marked as duplicate. Once I checked the original question, [Why do I get a recursion error with BeautifulSoup and IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19578749/977038) I was surprised to realize, this question was asked at a much later date Oct 24 '13, in contrasting to the duplicate question which was asked on Feb 14 '13.

These questions are indeed duplicate and I have no qualms except the fact that, when a question is closed as duplicate it shows that OP has not shown the necessary research effort required before asking a question.

What I would want to know is, what is the general practice when closing a question as duplicate particularly when the associated comment when a question is marked as a duplicate says that

*"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."*

So, if we have two questions Q1 and Q2 where Q1 was asked at an earlier date, can Q1 be closed as a duplicate of Q2 even though Q1 may not have any answer or not have drawn enough attention.

Comment: Also see [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we really mark new questions as duplicates of old crappy ones?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258697/should-we-really-mark-new-questions-as-duplicates-of-old-crappy-ones) or [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers)

Answer (score 4):

I had answered the newer post *at some point in the past*.

Today the question was asked again, and remembering I had encountered the problem before I searched and I found several more such questions, all without explaining what is going wrong and many without a solution. I cleaned up and closed those as duplicates of the one question that does have a clear explanation as to what the problem is and what the work-around is.

There is no hard and fast rule about duplicates having to be closed with the older post taking precedence; *the goal is to provide a canonical answer here*. In the majority of cases that means the canonical post is the older one, but that wasn't the case here.

Your post had no answer at all. Rather than duplicate my answer to your question, I closed it as a duplicate of the post that does have an answer.

Comment: `There is no hard and fast rule about duplicates having to be closed with the older post taking precedence; `, if this is the case then the comment is misleading "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."

Comment: So you insist on parentheses around "before", or some other clarification? Write a feature-request.

Comment: @Abhijit: The comment works for the majority of cases; there is a [feature request on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238520/should-the-closed-as-duplicate-message-be-altered) if you care enough about the text.

Comment: My problem is that this answer doesn't cover the general case.  And the suggested meta duplicates don't appear to address the fact that one question was asked after another.  The specific question has solid upvoted answers on the original, but it is now marked as a duplicate of a newer question.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: it does answer the general case: *There is no hard and fast rule about duplicates having to be closed with the older post taking precedence; the goal is to provide a canonical answer here.*