# Personal message/Rep change indicator on SE tab-page title

Tags: discussion, feature-request, global-inbox

Usually I'm working on a filtered question feed, and new activities are indicated in the tab title, e.g.

```
(1) Newest c++ Questions
```

The `(1)` usually indicates that a new question appeared on the feed.

> Could we count in personal events (as from the Inbox), to be visually indicated somehow at the tab title as well?
>   **Note please:** The feature I'm requesting just relates to the tab's title display.

May be s.th. like

```
(0/1) Newest c++ Questions
```

for no Inbox message, *one activity in the feed*.
Or may be even better, *zero activity on the feed, but 1 Inbox message* (and thus shortcut to `(1)` for *one feed activity*, as used to).

**UPDATE:**
The even better, and more concise visualization IMHO

```
(0+) Newest c++ Questions
```

Where `+` indicates any profile activity as Inbox-Messages or Reputation-Change.

**UPDATE 2:**
To avoid confusion with mathematical relations to the number indicating the number of new activities, a different symbol (more neutral) could be used as well, e.g.

```
(0●) Newest c++ Questions
```

---

Or leave out the zero and show numbers only, when there are also activities:

```
(●) Newest c++ Questions
```

*(Zero activities, any profile event)*

```
(1●) Newest c++ Questions
```

*(One new activity, any profile event)*

Comment: This is a great idea! Its really nice to know when you have an event pending, especially when it is a comment asking for clarification of a post.

Comment: I think the `(0/1)` syntax is a bit unclear unless you already know what it's referring to, although I suppose that would become clear after seeing it a few times. Very much in support of the idea, though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm used to have multiple tabs open in a (main) browser view, and switch between these on indicated activities (as far as available).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do the same, hence my support for this feature :)

Comment: @MikePrecup That's why I proposed my **"UPDATE"**, the small `+` would serve well anything I need ;-) ...

Comment: As someone who normally has enough tabs open that he only gets 2 or 3 characters of title text open at a time, I'm opposed to any clutter that displaces the bit of identifying information I have out about what that specific SO tab has in it out of sight.

Comment: The main idea is nice, however I'm also against encoding information in cryptic strings, so I need to remember their syntax to understand what they mean.

Comment: Can we also have `*` to indicate badges earned as well, while we're at it?

Comment: @Unihedron This would also fall under _profile activity_ as I mentioned, thus `+` would apply badges earned as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(2) inbox notification count in tab title bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255247/2-inbox-notification-count-in-tab-title-bar)

Comment: @MrD Yes, looks like a duplicate of the one you mentioned. Though, I gave some more constructive proposals IMHO.

Comment: I agree with @MrD that the requests are duplicates, but this one seems to have more traction in terms of votes, and more comments. Maybe they should be marked the other way around?

Comment: For the duplicate voters: That's not constructive, the only answer that's there now, is [**my proposal**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268888/1413395) :P ...

Answer (score 2):

> I'm replicating my answer to the [marked duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255247/inbox-notification-count-in-tab-title-bar) here:

---

We should have a notification notation on the tab page title like

```
(●) Newest 'javascript' ...
```

*(Zero activities, any profile event)*

```
(79●) Newest 'javascript' ...
```

*(79 new activities, any profile event)*

Where *profile event* (indicated as '●') is defined as any of

- Inbox message
- Reputation change
- Badge achievement

and *activities* is defined as the *"number of new questions"* as mentioned in your question.

---