# Can you please add the notification count for the title?

Tags: feature-request

Almost every time, I have around 5,6 tabs open in my browser. StackOverflow is always there. But I have to click the tab to check whether I have received a notification or not.

If you can change the title with count it is really good.

Gmail has already done this.

Note : I don't know think that this is a duplicate of [Personal message/Rep change indicator on SE tab-page title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268781/personal-message-rep-change-indicator-on-se-tab-page-title) since, here I asked about notification count and linked question is about activity count.

[image]

Comment: You get enough notifications to justify a feature like this?  I'm not necessarily *opposed* to what you're saying...but I'm not sure I see the true value here.

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to be notified when there is a new notification in a tab when it's not the principle tab. The actual number probably isn't that necessary. Just like how gmail, if you keep up on your emails, doesn't ever have more than a couple emails, but the notification lets you know that you've got mail.

Comment: @DavyM Yes, you are correct.... Please edit the question if my English is hard to understand... I am not native English speaker

Comment: I'd like this feature as well, mostly because I get so few notifications I'm not really camping this tab.

Comment: They've got a similar feature already for new questions when you're following a tag, I'm not sure they've got the space for this already. Showing a number with different meanings across the site would be weird. TBS, I'd love this.

Comment: What a nice idea! It would be roughly 20 lines in a userscript.

Comment: I rely on the number being the *number of new questions* (questions listing page). Please do not overload that meaning on different pages.